# Averaging values of dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have the following dataframe

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
'date': ['1988/01/12', '1988/01/13', '1988/01/14', '1989/01/20','1990/01/01'],
'value': [11558522, 12323552, 13770958, 18412280, 13770958]
})
```

Is there a way in python that I can average a value for a whole month and make that the new value for that month 
i.e. I want to average the 1988-01 value and make that the final value for 1988-01. I tried the groupby method but that didnt work

```
new_df=data.groupby(['date']).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use month periods created by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

new_df=data.groupby(data['date'].dt.to_period('m')).mean()
print (new_df)
                value
date                 
1988-01  1.255101e+07
1989-01  1.841228e+07
1990-01  1.377096e+07
```

Or use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and if necessary remove missing values:

```
new_df=data.resample('MS', on='date').mean().dropna()
print (new_df)
                   value
date                    
1988-01-01  1.255101e+07
1989-01-01  1.841228e+07
1990-01-01  1.377096e+07
```

Or you can use months and years separately for `MultiIndex`:

```
new_df=data.groupby([data['date'].dt.year.rename('y'),
                     data['date'].dt.month.rename('m')]).mean()
print (new_df)

               value
y    m              
1988 1  1.255101e+07
1989 1  1.841228e+07
1990 1  1.377096e+07
```

Comment: for some reason this works perfectly with the sample data but with my actual dataset it prints the values as 0. It prints out the dates correctly but the values are all 0 for the entire dataset

Comment: @Tamarie - First idea is check if data are numeric, hard question if yes.

Comment: yes its numeric. i ran data.dtypes i got datetime64 and float 64

Comment: @Tamarie - all 3 solutions failed?

Comment: all 3 solutions work they just dont print out the values (it's all blank). But i can see that it has 1 value for each month

Comment: @Tamarie - hmmm, weird. If check datetimes format is correct? Not swapped months with datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

df=pd.read_csv("data .csv",encoding='ISO-8859-1', parse_dates=["datetime"])
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

```
             datetime   Temperature
```

0     1987-11-01 07:00:00   21.4
1     1987-11-01 13:00:00   27.4
2     1987-11-01 19:00:00   25.0
3     1987-11-02 07:00:00   22.0
4     1987-11-02 13:00:00   27.6
...    ...
27554 2020-03-30 13:00:00   24.8
27555 2020-03-30 18:00:00   23.8
27556 2020-03-31 07:00:00   23.4
27557 2020-03-31 13:00:00   24.6
27558 2020-03-31 18:00:00   26.4

df1=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime',freq='D')).mean()

datetime    Temperature
1987-11-01  24.600000
1987-11-02  25.066667
1987-11-03  24.466667
1987-11-04  22.533333
1987-11-05  25.066667
...
2020-03-27  26.533333
2020-03-28  27.666667
2020-03-29  27.733333
2020-03-30  24.266667
2020-03-31  24.800000

Comment: You're right; the groupBy was failing on strings and parsing to datetime solves that. Explaining that a bit might make this less cryptic.

Comment: You're right Jim Meyer, the first thing is to pass the date and time that comes by default as an object. If it is not done, the error. And the pandas.Grouper function allows to specify a groupby statement (datetime & frec D)
data = pd.read_csv ("TTPM_POTOSI2.csv", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', parse_dates = ["Datetime"])
                     datetime   temperature
0 1987-11-01 07:00:00 21.4
1 1987-11-01 13:00:00 27.4
2 1987-11-01 19:00:00 25.0

df1 = data.groupby (pd.Grouper (key = 'datetime', freq = 'D')). mean ()
          datetime   temperature
1987-11-01 24.600000
1987-11-02 25.066667